# SyntaxException: while creating Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to create a simple table in cassandra, this is the command I run,

```
create table app_instance(app_id int, app_name varchar, proc_id varchar, os_priority int, cpu_time int, num_io_ops int, primary_key (host_id, proc_id)) with clustering order by (proc_id DESC) ;
```

I get the following error,

```
SyntaxException: line 1:132 no viable alternative at input '(' (...int, num_io_ops int, primary_key [(]...)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It is `primary key`, not `primary_key`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be **primary key**, with a space, not **primary_key**, as ernest_k already noted in a comment.
The way you wrote it,

> ...cpu_time int, num_io_ops int, primary_key (host_id, proc_id)

the CQL parser thinks that "primary_key" is the name of yet another column, just as num_io_ops was, and now expects to see the name of the type - and doesn't expect an open parenthesis after the "primary_key", and this is exactly what the error message told you (albeit vaguely).